# How do we append values to dictionary containing 3 elements in swift 2.3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am trying to append value to dictionary which I have declared like this.

```
var setHomIconDict:[(iconImg: UIImage, Operator: String, oprCode: String, oprMerchCode:String)]!
```

I am not sure its dictionary though. I am learning swift and I found a Intresting code on net. Anyway I am confused on how will I append values to this. I tried

```
setHomIconDict.append((iconImg:img!, Operator: "Strin", oprCode: "Hello", oprMerchCode: "Huja"))
```

But i get this error : fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value . here is the image[image]

Can anyone suggest an appropriate way.

Comment: create a model class for your required data . Then create an array of your model class. Append your model class objects into array with all the required values.

Answer (score 2):

`setHomIconDict` is not `Dictionary` it is an Array of tuple and you are getting this crash because you haven't initialized the `setHomIconDict` object, you have just declared its type. So initialized it with its declaration.

```
var setHomIconDict:[(iconImg: UIImage, Operator: String, oprCode: String, oprMerchCode:String)] = []
```

**Note:** Instead of creating array of tuple better solution is to create one custom model `Class` with the property that you want to `set/access`, then create array of that custom `Class` objects and use it.

Comment: It should be initialized as the following: = []

Comment: var setHomIconDict:[(iconImg: UIImage, Operator: String, oprCode: String, oprMerchCode:String)] = []

Comment: @hasan83 Edited answer for that :)

Answer (score 2):

You are probably better off creating a struct to hold your values. Then your array would be an array of that struct.

```
struct homIcon {
    var iconImg: UIImage
    var Operator: String
    var oprCode: String
    var oprMerchCode:String
}

var setHomIconArray:[homIcon] = []

let newHomIcon = homIcon(iconImg: img!, Operator: "Strin", oprCode: "Hello", oprMerchCode: "Huja")

setHomIconArray.append(newHomIcon)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Nirav says, the syntax you are using creates an array of tuples. If you want a dictionary get rid of the parentheses.

You want to define key/value pairs using this syntax:

```
var aDict = [key:value, key:value, key:value]
```

Then you can add new key/value pairs using:

```
aDict[newKey] = newValue
```

Is your goal to create and use a dictionary, or is it your goal to user and understand the structure that you found on the net?